# Find all files except those which is under version control systems (git or SVN)

Tags: git, bash, svn, shell, unix

I have to find all files on my computer except those which is under version control systems (git or SVN). I don't have to find not only meta files of VCS but all files in my working copy so i can't use something like

`find . -type f \! -path \*/\.svn/\*;`

Please, help me, cause i haven't any idea about it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `git status` and `svn status` returns non-zero exit codes if current working directory (CWD) is not a repository. Since I don't think find can suppress output of its `-exec` invocations I would create

~/gitstatus.sh:

```
git status > /dev/null 2>&1
exit $?
```

~/svnstatus.sh:

```
svn status > /dev/null 2>&1
exit $?
```

Searching the files would then be done by issuing:

```
find . -type f '!' '(' -execdir bash ~/gitstatus.sh ';' -or -execdir bash ~/gitstatus.sh ';' ')'
```

Comment: I've just launched it, but output list contains only
`find: ./System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default: Permission denied
find: ./System/Library/User Template: Permission denied
find: ./Users/Guest/Desktop: Permission denied
find: ./Users/Guest/Music: Permission denied
find: ./Users/Guest/Pictures: Permission denied
find: ./Users/Guest/Public/Drop Box: Permission denied`

etc. What's wrong?

Comment: The issue is that you don't have permission to list files in those directories. Based on the files listed, it looks like you are running a Mac. Try adding `sudo ` before `find` and entering your password and you should be fine. However, beware when using `sudo` because it gives the program you are running administrators' access!